# Why is mb_convert_encoding returning false?

Tags: php, encoding

Here is my code:

```
static function CreateHash($password) {
    $upass = mb_convert_encoding($password,'UCS-2LE','auto');

    // note I have tried calling the following function to get the 
    // encoding type of $password and it returns ASCII
    // $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($password);
}
```

If I call the above function with $password = "abc123!", `mb_convert_encoding` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

> "auto" is expanded to "ASCII,JIS,UTF-8,EUC-JP,SJIS"

But in my case it did not work correctly. If I try the following code instead of `'auto'` I get the expected result:

```
$upass = mb_convert_encoding($password, 'UCS-2LE', "ASCII,JIS,UTF-8,EUC-JP,SJIS");
```

Comment: FWIW, why do you need to guess from several encodings in the first place? You should expect your string to be in *one single encoding*.

Comment: @deceze: I am new to PHP and have recently started working on this code... The password comes from website. Are you suggesting that it is always in ASCII format? so I should use: `mb_convert_encoding($password, 'UCS-2LE', "ASCII");` instead?

Comment: Yes, if you expect it to be in ASCII, specify only that encoding explicitly.